# Find the probability of each column in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, probability, montecarlo

I'm using the Monte Carlo approach to generate `N` scenarios for my random variable.  I store these scenarios in a `M x N` matrix. I want to compute the probability of each scenario (column) occurring in the matrix.

I tried to use the command `histc()` but it doesn't work.  How can I find these probabilities and store them in a vector in order to use it for an optimization problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) on the transpose of this "scenario" matrix and examine the third output of the function call.  The third output assigns a unique ID to every possible unique occurrence seen in the matrix.  You'll also want to specify the `'rows'` flag to consider each row in its entirety to be a single instance.  If you don't specify `'rows'`, each individual element in your matrix would be considered a single instance where you want the entire column (or row of the transposed matrix) to be a single instance.  Also, we can't operate along the columns with `unique` unfortunately which is why you need to transpose the matrix instead.

You'll also want the first output too to examine how each ID maps to each unique occurrence.  Make sure you transpose this output variable at the end to make the outputs map to columns.  You can then use `histc` or `histcounts` to determine the occurrence of each "scenario" and thus find the probability assuming an equiprobable situation.

Here's a quick example.  Suppose I have this matrix of events stored in `A`:

```
>> A = [0 0 0; 1 1 1; 1 0 0; 0 0 1; 0 0 0; 0 0 1; 1 1 1].'

A =

     0     1     1     0     0     0     1
     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
     0     1     0     1     0     1     1
```

We see that the dimensionality of the scenario is 3 while there are 7 events.  Doing what I said with `unique` gives:

```
>> [un, ~, id] = unique(A.', 'rows'); %'
>> un = un.' %'

un =

     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     1
     0     1     0     1

>> id

id =

     1
     4
     3
     2
     1
     2
     4
```

We can see that the column `[0; 0; 0]` belongs to ID 1, the column `[0; 0; 1]` maps to ID 2, the column `[1; 0; 0]` maps to ID 3 and finally `[1; 1; 1]` maps to ID 4.   `un` stores all unique columns while `id` provides us this mapping.  You can verify that if you consult the `id` variable and consult the mapping we have seen above, you can replace each column with their corresponding IDs.

We can then determine the probabilities of each occurrence:

```
N = size(un,2); %// Get total number of unique scenarios
M = size(A,2); %// Get total number of scenarios
prob = histc(id, 1 : N) / M; %// Finding probabilities
```

We get:

```
>> prob

prob =

    0.2857
    0.2857
    0.1429
    0.2857
```

This agrees with our data.  For columns `[0; 0; 0]`, `[0; 0; 1]` and `[1; 1; 1]`, there are two occurrences of each column and so the probabilities are `2/7 = 0.2857`.  The other column of `[1; 0; 0]` only has one occurrence, and so the probability is `1/7 = 0.1429`.

---

For the full code listing so you can easily copy and paste, assuming your matrix is stored in `A`:

```
[un, ~, id] = unique(A.', 'rows'); %'// Assigning each event a unique ID
un = un.'; %'// Transpose to ensure compatibility
N = size(un,2); %// Get total number of unique scenarios
M = size(A,2); %// Get total number of scenarios
prob = histc(id, 1 : N) / M; %// Finding probabilities
```